# Start rtp without sessioning protocol

Tags: sip, rtp, sdp

Is it possible to have one way streaming via RTP without the initiation of an RTP session via SIP or some other protocol?

In other words, if a streaming source just starts sending RTP packets, can they be interpreted by the destination if no sessions have been initialized prior the sending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can. But there have to be many preset parameters:

1. Ip and ports used.
2. Codecs used.
3. Codec configuration parameters

   ...

And, of course, you have to make sure that the receptor is ready to accept the packets sent, etc.

In other words: you can, but you should take care of all those things that SIP, RTSP, or other protocols do when setting up a multimedia session.

Comment: Why can't the receiver know what codec is being used from the `RTP:Payload type`?

Comment: Cause some codecs use dynamic payload types. But, if you choose a codec, and make both receiver and sender agree in what codec is the one to be used (hardcoding it in both sides, for example); or, otherwise, use always codecs with registered payload types, this will not be an issue.

Comment: But, anyway, the purpose of the session setup protocols is to allow to agree on codecs to be used, because not every endpoint in the session has to support the same codecs. They have to negotiate a common subset.